# Linux server high load spikes

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, high-load

I'm facing high load spikes on a linux server (Ubuntu 18.04, 16 core, 8GB Ram) : it is a webserver with apache 2.4, php7.2-fpm and memcached, no database services (which are provided by different server).

Those spikes are very fast and lasts for few seconds,
[this is what top shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBQMm.png)

At first I thought it depends on abnormal CPU usage but, as shown in the picture, there is no process who made high use of cpu and RAM usage is relative low (25%).
Instead the problem seems to be wa which are very high!

I've tried to investigate if it depends on I/O storage problem using iotop but it seems that when those spikes happened there is no increases of I/O reads or writes.

Those spikes happened many times in a day and, after some monitoring, I saw that they happened al specific time.
I checked if exists processes scheduled to run at that specific time but haven't found anything.

I know that other high load causes could also depends by high bandwith usage but how can I monitor this?

I'm not very experienced with iostat o sar, are they "the right way"  to troubleshooting my problem?

As *Matthew Ife* suggested I've tried with `ps -ALo pid,tid,comm,wchan` in high load moment and it gives some interesting output:

```
 35227  35227 kworker/12:2    worker_thread
 53730  53730 kworker/7:0     worker_thread
 57306  57306 php-fpm7.2      poll_schedule_timeout
 57348  57348 php-fpm7.2      poll_schedule_timeout
 57988  57988 php-fpm7.2      poll_schedule_timeout
 58251  58251 php-fpm7.2      poll_schedule_timeout
 60181  60181 kworker/5:2     worker_thread
 62158  62158 kworker/2:1     worker_thread
 62169  62169 php-fpm7.2      poll_schedule_timeout
 65001  65001 php-fpm7.2      poll_schedule_timeout
 69262  69262 php-fpm7.2      poll_schedule_timeout
 69647  69647 kworker/6:1     worker_thread
 72110  72110 php-fpm7.2      call_rwsem_down_write_failed
 72638  72638 php-fpm7.2      skb_wait_for_more_packets
 72845  72845 php-fpm7.2      call_rwsem_down_write_failed
 72848  72848 php-fpm7.2      call_rwsem_down_write_failed
 72850  72850 php-fpm7.2      skb_wait_for_more_packets
 72892  72892 php-fpm7.2      skb_wait_for_more_packets
 72909  72909 kworker/u256:2  worker_thread
 72940  72940 kworker/u256:4  get_write_access
 73353  73353 top             poll_schedule_timeout
 73367  73367 php-fpm7.2      locks_lock_inode_wait
 73659  73659 php-fpm7.2      call_rwsem_down_write_failed
 73950  73950 php-fpm7.2      skb_wait_for_more_packets
 73953  73953 php-fpm7.2      call_rwsem_down_write_failed
 74259  74259 php-fpm7.2      skb_wait_for_more_packets
 74345  74345 php-fpm7.2      skb_wait_for_more_packets
 74436  74436 kworker/13:1    worker_thread
 74481  74481 kworker/u256:1  get_write_access
 74519  74519 php-fpm7.2      skb_wait_for_more_packets
 74522  74522 php-fpm7.2      skb_wait_for_more_packets
 74576  74576 php-fpm7.2      call_rwsem_down_write_failed
 74578  74578 php-fpm7.2      skb_wait_for_more_packets
 74603  74603 php-fpm7.2      locks_lock_inode_wait
 74849  74849 php-fpm7.2      skb_wait_for_more_packets
 75085  75085 php-fpm7.2      skb_wait_for_more_packets
 75088  75088 php-fpm7.2      call_rwsem_down_write_failed
 75100  75100 php-fpm7.2      call_rwsem_down_write_failed
 75171  75171 php-fpm7.2      skb_wait_for_more_packets
 75283  75283 kworker/2:2     worker_thread
....
```

Does this mean that there's some problem with filesystem or storage?

Comment: IO wait does not cause load - until the system is in a *really* bad state.

Comment: IOWait doesn't necessarily always directly mean IO but sometimes other "kernel thread is busy" scenarios. Whilst you see it in this state, try to provide a output of `ps -ALo pid,tid,comm,wchan` and provide the output. If you're using NFS it may relate to that.

Comment: Do you have any NFS mounts?

Comment: High 5min LA and high wait indicate that there were a lot of processes in an uninterruptable state. Run `top` and add a filter with `o` to `S=D` to see these stuck processes.

Comment: @AlexD : no NFS mount.

Comment: @symcbean : Thanks for your comment, but "really bad state" isn't that usefull, don't you think? Personally I found problem in past were IO wait caused by storage problem caused high load, unfortunately this not that case. In your opinion where I should look to find out hig load causes? Thanks

Comment: You can collect system I/O data with `sar -d 60 60` with intervals of 60 seconds for 60 periods (tune to your taste). If you really don't have any I/O spikes I would start looking for storage device errors and timeouts in the logs.

Comment: @AlexD I'm trying to find them but it seems there's no I/O spikes or, at least, they were so fast I cannot trace them. Please give a look at my answer below, maybe it could be usefull, thanks

Answer (score 3):

A few things pop out to me

```
kworker/u256:1  get_write_access
php-fpm7.2      call_rwsem_down_write_failed
php-fpm7.2      locks_lock_inode_wait
```

What this is telling you is that `php` is doing some file locking using `fcntl` or `flock`.

If you catch it again you can try doing something like this to print out the entire kernel stack for the stuck process(es). It often yields more information pertaining to the stuck filesystem in the backtrace.

```
for p in $(ps -ho pid,wchan $(pgrep php-fpm7.2) | grep -E 'locks_lock_inode_wait|call_rwsem_down_write_failed'  | awk '{print $1}'); do 
    echo $p
    cat /proc/$p/stack
    echo
done
```

Also when this happens run the `lslocks` command and get a view of what files are being locked and where.

There isn't sufficient information in this post as of yet to determine what is happening or why this is broken. Its possible you've somehow managed to open a bajillion locks or something bizarre.

Its also possibly relating to the filesystem itself having a bug with file locking.
My bet however is its some remote filesystem or even some `fuse` filesystem that is mega slow.

Alternatively you've hit upon a kernel bug to do with locking -- this is the type of thing that (typically) gets caught so you might just find simply updating to the latest kernel and rebooting fixes the problem and squashes the bug.

Comment: thanks, I'll try these checks hoping to find how to solve the problem

Comment: Agree with looking into `/proc/$pid/stack` but I think `pgrep nginx` should be `pgrep php-fpm7.2`

Comment: Yes, I dont run fpm so used nginx to prototype :). Corrected it now.